# How to restrict html number input to have only numbers with only one dot allowed?

Tags: html, regex, angular, ecmascript-6, pattern-matching

I have pattern for numbers and decimal.

```
^\\d{0,16}(\\.\\d{0,6})?$
```

but this pattern allowing to enter multiple dots.

How not to allow multiple dots ?

Comment: use this one `([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)` here is the ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952093/how-to-allow-only-one-dot-in-regex

Comment: The pattern does not allow multiple dots https://regex101.com/r/RFmoVZ/1 Is does allow an empty string as all the parts are optional.